# JSHint redefinition warning and adding more properties to object

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have object definition spanning multiple files and I use the following syntax to add more properties to namespace

```
var app = app || {};

// and then
app.namespace = {
  ...
}
```

But JSHint warns me with stuff like:

```
[L1:C5] W079: Redefinition of 'app'.
var app = app || {};
```

I'm not sure if this is really wrong as I've seen it used many times e.g. together with module pattern.

If that's ok, how can I globally supress that warning? I've found a way to supress given option for given file with

```
/* jshint: -W079 */
```

but is there a way to do it globally? Or is it considered bad practice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this:

```
window.app = window.app || {};
```

What you are trying is assigning the local variable **app** to the global variable **app**.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Actually result is the same on the top level I guess :) Thanks.